# Display year with Moment JS

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

Using Moment JS, I'm trying to display a start and end year where the end year is 11 months after the start year. I'm having no issue displaying the start year, but the end year is showing with odd formatting. I'm getting: 01 January 2021 - 31 December 31536002021.

What do I need to do to format that end year as just a 4 digit year?

calendar.component.ts:

```
  public startMonth: string = moment.months()[0];
  public startYear: number = moment().year();
  public endMonth: string = moment.months()[11];
  public endYear = moment(this.startYear).add(11, 'M');
```

Answer (score 0):

`moment().year()` returns a number, so when you define `endYear` moment is trying to create a date from a [Unix timestamp](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) - or, in your case, 2021 milliseconds from the Unix Epoch (Jan 1 1970 12AM UTC).

Try casting startYear to a string before passing it to moment, or read the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing) for a plethora of ways to format, parse, and modify dates.

```
// the add function returns a moment object, so you can continue to format as you see fit
public endYear = moment(String(this.startYear)).add(11, 'M');
```